# 3 tables MySQL join with non-shared atributes

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables, with the following (hypothetical) columns:

- `student(name_id,time,pers)`
- `job(name_id,work_id,salary)`
- `departament(work_id,project)`

Now let's say I want to request the value of "pers", contained in the table `student` that matches with a certain project from the table `department`. I see that I first have to join `department` with `job`, and then the result with `student` to finally select the column I am interested in; but I'm not really sure how to do it, and everything I've tried has failed.

Could you guys give me any hint on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Always post you attempt, even if it was a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right starting idea, you want to do a join between the department and job and the student. Perhaps you don't know how to do joins in mysql? It should look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM department d 
JOIN job j USING(work_id)
JOIN student s USING(name_id)
WHERE d.project = 'project'
```

This might not give you the exact results you are looking for as there could be many relationships to one student.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem I've been facing, but it seems now to be solved. I've been trying to do the same but with a more rudimentary query, not involving JOINs directly, so there's been something I didn't take into account. Thanks for yout help.